# Remove the uppercase from product names in RWD theme

Tags: magento-1.9, rwd-theme, rwd

I'm having a bit of difficulty locating where to change the case setting in the RWD theme css files.

I'm looking to remove the uppercase settings from the product names - any ideas?

Using 1.9

Thanks

Comment: Check your back end product name if you set capital or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under **/skin/frontend/rwd/default/scss/mixin/_typography.scss** line 108, remove the text-transform propriety:

```
@mixin pageTitle() {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: $c-text;
    border-bottom: 1px solid $c-module-border-light;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: Hi DP - I found these in the css file, however I can't seem to locate the same details within the SCSS files - sorry I should have mentioned that I was using SASS.

Comment: See my edit with SCSS

Comment: Brilliant thank you. For reference in case anyone else comes across this issue - I also had to remove "text-transform: uppercase;" from /skin/frontend/rwd/default/scss/module/_product-list.scss line 88